# On hover img; highlight list items corresponding to img classes

Tags: jquery

I'm working with images and lists.

The images have classes as follows:

`year_2010` `artist_picasso` `color_green`

The lists are structured as follows:

```
<ol>
    <h1>year</h1>
    <li class="year_2009">2009</li>
    <li class="year_2010">2010</li>
    <li class="year_2011">2011</li>
</ol>
<ol>
    <h1>artist</h1>
    <li class="artist_matisse">Matisse</li>
    <li class="artist_miro">Miro</li>
    <li class="artist_picasso">Picasso</li>
</ol>
<ol>
    <h1>color</h1>
    <li class="color_blue">Blue</li>
    <li class="color_green">Green</li>
    <li class="color_red">Red</li>
</ol>
```

I'm trying to highlight list items, that correspond with the classes of the image that is being hovered.

e.g. hover over the image of a *green* painting by *Picasso* made in *2010* (I know he is dead) I wish to highlight list items 'Green', 'Picasso' and '2010'.

I'm new to jQuery. This is what I have so far. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('img').hover(function() {
    $('ol > li' + this.className).addClass('highlight');
    },function() {
        $('ol > li' + this.className).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

```js
$('img').hover(function() {
    $('ol > li' + this.className).addClass('highlight');
    },function() {
        $('ol > li' + this.className).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
img {
  height:100px;
  padding:20px
}

h1, ol li {
  font-size:15px;
}

ol li.highlight {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://d32dm0rphc51dk.cloudfront.net/E5iZNtcgKXbzgohbM-XXpA/large.jpg" class="year_2010 artist_picasso color_green">

<ol>
    <h1>year</h1>
    <li class="year_2009">2009</li>
    <li class="year_2010">2010</li>
    <li class="year_2011">2011</li>
</ol>
<ol>
    <h1>artist</h1>
    <li class="artist_matisse">Matisse</li>
    <li class="artist_miro">Miro</li>
    <li class="artist_picasso">Picasso</li>
</ol>
<ol>
    <h1>color</h1>
    <li class="color_blue">Blue</li>
    <li class="color_green">Green</li>
    <li class="color_red">Red</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get class attribute then `split` that value and generate comma separated value using `map` then pass this as your selector to highlight particular `lis`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('img').hover(function() {
  //get class split it and then generated comma seperated value..
  var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(" ").map(function(value) {
    return "li." + value;
  }).join(",")
  $(classes).addClass('highlight'); //add there classs
}, function() {
  $('ol > li').removeClass('highlight'); //remove class
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/_Sy7qYNsid8VYlalMQG871VgqMl7gUa5BZQbM8Gc2LkHW5kogHgvSsaiEYA00L3xakszWexpCTPnjJlmFt9APyvrAyQmF7jhP1Wr_G6Yccu0FBKS4SlgNHWgdQ" class="year_2010 artist_picasso color_green">
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/_Sy7qYNsid8VYlalMQG871VgqMl7gUa5BZQbM8Gc2LkHW5kogHgvSsaiEYA00L3xakszWexpCTPnjJlmFt9APyvrAyQmF7jhP1Wr_G6Yccu0FBKS4SlgNHWgdQ" class="year_2009 artist_matisse color_blue">
<ol>
  <h1>year</h1>
  <li class="year_2008">2008</li>
  <li class="year_2009">2009</li>
  <li class="year_2010">2010</li>
  <li class="year_2011">2011</li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <h1>artist</h1>
  <li class="year_DavidHockney">Hockney</li>
  <li class="artist_matisse">Matisse</li>
  <li class="artist_miro">Miro</li>
  <li class="artist_picasso">Picasso</li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <h1>color</h1>
  <li class="color_blue">Blue</li>
  <li class="color_green">Green</li>
  <li class="color_red">Red</li>
</ol>
```